# How do I add JSON data in the child table against the parent table in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have been struggling with something in Ruby on Rails.

I have four tables which are interlinked: `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. `A` is the parent for `B` and `B` is the parent for `C` and `D`.

I have a records already existing in table `B` and want to add multiple entries against a particular record, for example "3", in the 'C' and 'D' tables against this id.

The data format is:

```
[{\"waypoint\":{\"latitude\":37.3645616666667,\"timestamp\":\"2012-10-16T09:58:50Z\",\"background\":false,\"estimated_speed\":17.4189262390137,\"journey_id\":null,\"longitude\":-112.850676666667}},{\"waypoint\":{\"latitude\":37.3648733333333,\"timestamp\":\"2012-10-16T09:58:54Z\",\"background\":false,\"estimated_speed\":17.076057434082,\"journey_id\":null,\"longitude\":-112.85077}},{\"waypoint\":{\"latitude\":37.3651116666667,\"timestamp\":\"2012-10-16T09:58:57Z\",\"background\":false,\"estimated_speed\":15.4269437789917,\"journey_id\":null,\"longitude\":-112.850766666667}},{\"waypoint\":{\"latitude\":37.36547,\"timestamp\":\"2012-10-16T09:59:02Z\",\"background\":false,\"estimated_speed\":17.1007328033447,\"journey_id\":null,\"longitude\":-112.85072}},{\"waypoint\":{\"latitude\":37.3658433333333,\"timestamp\":\"2012-10-16T09:59:11Z\",\"background\":false,\"estimated_speed\":10.3052024841309,\"journey_id\":null,\"longitude\":-112.850738333333}}]"
```

I get this data from a web service. But I see `journey_id` as null, whereas I want it to be `3`, as I want to make the entry against this id.

How can I save this data in a child table using this id?

Comment: Your question wasn't worded well at all, so I tried to simplify and clarify it to help us make sense of it. You want to save a JSON string, but don't understand how to modify the "null" value, either by parsing the JSON into a hash and modifying the value for `journey_id`, or directly by using string manipulation. And you're doing this in Rails? I think you've bitten off a lot more than you can chew, as I seems you are missing basic Ruby skills. I'd strongly recommend starting with the basics and put your Rails aside a while. Rails will make a LOT more sense once you know those things.

Comment: Thanks .. yes , I am not a professional ROR developer. I know that my wording is perfect , but I tried what I need to do ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON string isn't opened correctly in your sample, as it's missing the leading `'"'`. Fixing that and moving on, here's what the JSON looks like "prettified":

```
[
  {
    "waypoint": {
      "latitude": 37.3645616666667,
      "timestamp": "2012-10-16T09:58:50Z",
      "background": false,
      "estimated_speed": 17.4189262390137,
      "journey_id": null,
      "longitude": -112.850676666667
    }
  },
  {
    "waypoint": {
      "latitude": 37.3648733333333,
      "timestamp": "2012-10-16T09:58:54Z",
      "background": false,
      "estimated_speed": 17.076057434082,
      "journey_id": null,
      "longitude": -112.85077
    }
  },
  {
    "waypoint": {
      "latitude": 37.3651116666667,
      "timestamp": "2012-10-16T09:58:57Z",
      "background": false,
      "estimated_speed": 15.4269437789917,
      "journey_id": null,
      "longitude": -112.850766666667
    }
  },
  {
    "waypoint": {
      "latitude": 37.36547,
      "timestamp": "2012-10-16T09:59:02Z",
      "background": false,
      "estimated_speed": 17.1007328033447,
      "journey_id": null,
      "longitude": -112.85072
    }
  },
  {
    "waypoint": {
      "latitude": 37.3658433333333,
      "timestamp": "2012-10-16T09:59:11Z",
      "background": false,
      "estimated_speed": 10.3052024841309,
      "journey_id": null,
      "longitude": -112.850738333333
    }
  }
]
```

You have an array of `waypoint` objects. Parsing that JSON into a Ruby object:

```
obj = JSON["[{\"waypoint\":..."] # purposely truncated for brevity
```

returns an array of hashes:

```
[{"waypoint"=>
   {"latitude"=>37.3645616666667,
    "timestamp"=>"2012-10-16T09:58:50Z",
    "background"=>false,
    "estimated_speed"=>17.4189262390137,
    "journey_id"=>nil,
    "longitude"=>-112.850676666667}},
 {"waypoint"=>
   {"latitude"=>37.3648733333333,
    "timestamp"=>"2012-10-16T09:58:54Z",
    "background"=>false,
    "estimated_speed"=>17.076057434082,
    "journey_id"=>nil,
    "longitude"=>-112.85077}},
 {"waypoint"=>
   {"latitude"=>37.3651116666667,
    "timestamp"=>"2012-10-16T09:58:57Z",
    "background"=>false,
    "estimated_speed"=>15.4269437789917,
    "journey_id"=>nil,
    "longitude"=>-112.850766666667}},
 {"waypoint"=>
   {"latitude"=>37.36547,
    "timestamp"=>"2012-10-16T09:59:02Z",
    "background"=>false,
    "estimated_speed"=>17.1007328033447,
    "journey_id"=>nil,
    "longitude"=>-112.85072}},
 {"waypoint"=>
   {"latitude"=>37.3658433333333,
    "timestamp"=>"2012-10-16T09:59:11Z",
    "background"=>false,
    "estimated_speed"=>10.3052024841309,
    "journey_id"=>nil,
    "longitude"=>-112.850738333333}}]
```

You can walk through that array and access, or change, the value for `journey_id`:

```
row = 3
obj = obj.map{ |h| h['waypoint']['journey_id'] = row }
obj.first
```

Looking at the first hash shows the value was changed, as were all the rest:

```
{
  "waypoint" => {
    "latitude" => 37.3645616666667,
    "timestamp" => "2012-10-16T09:58:50Z",
    "background" => false,
    "estimated_speed" => 17.4189262390137,
    "journey_id" => 3,
    "longitude" => -112.850676666667
  }
}
```

At that point, you need to recreate the JSON string. You can figure that out by reading [the JSON documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html).

You could do all this by modifying the received string directly, but you don't want to get into the habit of directly modifying JSON strings because you can inadvertently damage the payload. It's better to let the parser give you the structure, modify that, then let JSON recreate the string.

How you store it to your database is left as an exercise for you also.

Comment: Thanks for you response. How can i save this json in the child table "C"

Comment: "How you store it to your database is left as an exercise for you also."

Comment: Hi Tin Man , could you help me to save the data . I tried different ways , but it through the error .